# Reshaping a data frame by "combining" columns in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with url strings and am using the stringr package in R to produce new columns with a boolean on whether the string contains an element or not.

```
library(stringr)

url = data.frame(u=c("http://www.subaru.com/vehicles/impreza/index.html",
        "http://www.subaru.com/index.html?s_kwcid=subaru&k_clickid=214495e6-dbe0-6668-9222-00003d7cd876&prid=87&k_affcode=76602",
        "http://www.subaru.com/customer-support.html",
        "http://www.subaru.com/",
        "http://www.subaru.com/vehicles/forester/index.html"))
url

cs = c("customer-support")
f = c("forester")
one_match <- str_c(cs, collapse = "|")
two_match <- str_c(f, collapse = "|")

main <- function(df) {
  df$customer_support <- as.numeric(str_detect(url$u, one_match))
  df
}
d1 = main(url)

main <- function(df) {
  df$forester <- as.numeric(str_detect(url$u, two_match))
  df
}
d2 = main(url)

mydt = join(d1, d2)
mydt
```

The above code produces the following results.

> mydt

```
    u
1                                                                      http://www.subaru.com/vehicles/impreza/index.html
2 http://www.subaru.com/index.html?s_kwcid=subaru&k_clickid=214495e6-dbe0-6668-9222-00003d7cd876&prid=87&k_affcode=76602
3                                                                            http://www.subaru.com/customer-support.html
4                                                                                                 http://www.subaru.com/
5                                                                     http://www.subaru.com/vehicles/forester/index.html
  customer_support forester
1                0        0
2                0        0
3                1        0
4                0        0
5                0        1
```

What I want to do is reshape the data frame so that I restructure columns 2 and 3 so that they are combined and no longer boolean values

It should look like:

```
page
0
0
customer_support
0
forester
```

I've tried many different things, including variations of reshape, transform, dcast, etc and nothing seems to get the job done. Can anyone help me get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write such complicated functions.. You can simply use `grepl` and `ifelse` functions as below

```
urldata = data.frame(u = c("http://www.subaru.com/vehicles/impreza/index.html", "http://www.subaru.com/index.html?s_kwcid=subaru&k_clickid=214495e6-dbe0-6668-9222-00003d7cd876&prid=87&k_affcode=76602", 
    "http://www.subaru.com/customer-support.html", "http://www.subaru.com/", "http://www.subaru.com/vehicles/forester/index.html"))

cs = c("customer-support")
f = c("forester")

urldata
##                                                                                                                        u
## 1                                                                      http://www.subaru.com/vehicles/impreza/index.html
## 2 http://www.subaru.com/index.html?s_kwcid=subaru&k_clickid=214495e6-dbe0-6668-9222-00003d7cd876&prid=87&k_affcode=76602
## 3                                                                            http://www.subaru.com/customer-support.html
## 4                                                                                                 http://www.subaru.com/
## 5                                                                     http://www.subaru.com/vehicles/forester/index.html

urldata$page <- ifelse(grepl(cs, urldata$u), cs, ifelse(grepl(f, urldata$u), f, 0))
urldata
##                                                                                                                        u
## 1                                                                      http://www.subaru.com/vehicles/impreza/index.html
## 2 http://www.subaru.com/index.html?s_kwcid=subaru&k_clickid=214495e6-dbe0-6668-9222-00003d7cd876&prid=87&k_affcode=76602
## 3                                                                            http://www.subaru.com/customer-support.html
## 4                                                                                                 http://www.subaru.com/
## 5                                                                     http://www.subaru.com/vehicles/forester/index.html
##               page
## 1                0
## 2                0
## 3 customer-support
## 4                0
## 5         forester
```